# Screen not coming back after suspension or sleep on Lenovo Legion 5 pro running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, suspend, lenovo

I recently bought a Lenovo Legion 5 pro. Ubuntu does not support a few things on this device, since there are a lot of issues including Wifi/Bluetooth not working and not being able to adjust the screen brightness, but here I am addressing the one where the screen does not come back after sleeping or suspension of the session.

**Scenario One**

I close the lid, open it again, and no response. I can't see the screen irrespective of what I do, i.e clicking, pressing buttons on the keyboard or the power button.

**Scenario Two**

I click on the suspend option provided on the ubuntu menu, I move the cursor, the password screen comes back. Upon entering the password, the screen disappears again with no response. While doing some hit and trial, when the blank screen came again, I entered the password again and hit enter. I noticed the screen is very very dim to the point where I can't make out what's written or wheres what but I can see it a bit.

In both cases, the only option I am left with is a hard shut down.

**Kernel version is 5.11.0.37**

**Edit (17/10/2021)**

As suggested by @zanna, when I did the `systemctl suspend`, it had the normal suspension behavior where I could log back in with proper screen visibility. I am not sure what happened but it magically fixed the issue for now. (I do have my doubts if it will work when the Nvidia GPU is active, I changed it in windows to the dynamic mode and that seems to affect the ubuntu environment too.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Probably generic there is hwe kernel as well with for many people better hardware support.

Comment: Well, I installed mainline to see if there were kernel updates available or not, it didn't show me anything, I also read on a post that updated kernel can be dangerous?

Comment: Untested sure but HWE is simply another kernel stream and not dangerous.

Comment: I am assuming that I can revert back to initial kernel after changing it to another version in case things fail?

Comment: Yes when you boot do you notice the second option to boot Ubuntu with options maybe not quite that wording look at that it lets you choose other kernels other then the last running one.

Comment: Yes, there is an advanced options with options such as safe mode. Is that the one you are referring to?

Comment: Yes could not remember the name and not able to reboot to check it >)

Comment: So I am using this website to see the latest version `https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/` and according to this latest version is 5.15-rc4, I should install this one?

Comment: rc4 not fully tested.

Comment: Which ones are the tested ones?

Comment: Any that dont say rc which is release candidate they are still working them. You are only looking at mainline not HWE?

Comment: I am installing 5.14, I am doing this for the first time. :) After installation it said `errors encountered while processing linux-headers-5.14.11.051411-generic`. Should I be worried?

Comment: Reboot and find out is all I can say.

Comment: I just did ahah, It gave me an error. 
`error: /boot/vmlinuz-5.14.11-051411 has invalid signature.`
`error: you need the load the kernel first`

Comment: Well load an old kernel on boot up. I still think an HWE kernel might be better for you.

Comment: Apparently, that error is caused because mainline kernels are not signed and I need to turn off secure boot in bios which I am not sure is a good idea or not.

Also, I used this command ` hwe-support-status --verbose` the output came to be `Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2025.`, does that mean HWE is already there?

Comment: Secure boot should almost never be on when running Ubuntu. I do not know what that message means sorry.

Comment: What about the issues that come with disabling secure boot? or is it just a nuisance thing?

Comment: It is a feature that for the most part only windows wants.

Comment: I was able to load 5.14 kernel but it has a number of broken packages. It has also discarded my nividia drivers too. :) But it has fixed my wifi adapter problems.

Comment: 1 step forward 2 steps back but you will get there.

Comment: I just got back to my windows and suddenly the wifi adapter is not working- it doesn't make sense. Can i mess up my wifi with these things?

Comment: Not in windows.

Comment: Well it's bizzare, i can't fry hardware with kernel updates right?

Comment: no, the card will be okay... maybe it's turned off (like airplane mode) or there's a problem with the network, or try turning it off and on again. Anyway, with suspend/sleep, can you please [edit] and clarify your question to explain exactly when suspend does and does not work? I mean describe the behaviour & your actions in each case. I also suggest searching for your device on [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/) to see if anyone has figured out which kernel solves this. If you find the answer you can post it here. Ubuntu Forums is often better for new HW support struggles.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Zanna! The wifi adapter started working again after i restarted it the next day. I will put more details in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's much clearer (and good to know the wifi is okay at least in Windows!). Can you try running `systemctl suspend` in a terminal and see if you get any response or useful output?

Comment: After doing `systemctl suspend` the screen blacked out and upon using the cursor, I could put a password and the screen was visible.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/brightness-not-working-ubuntu-20-04-lenovo-legion-5-15imh05/178058/21

Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file add `nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

Then execute `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this by switching to Nouveau drivers under "Software & Updates" > "Additional Drivers".

And then rebooting the computer.

I noticed some weird behavior after doing a `systemctl suspend` (which was the first thing I tried after rebooting). Afterwards I could close my laptop and it would wake up correctly.

[image]

Comment: Bizzare enough, it started working by itself for me. I have no idea how.